# How to extract data from div, and display in other div within same page (bootstrap modal) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I tried fetching data by ids and then adding to local storage, but how to display the fetched data in different divs inside the modal. (didn't displayed the code for modal)**

**Code:**

```js
var cart = [];
            

function addItem(id) {
                var product = document.getElementById(`product-${id}`).innerHTML;
                var price = document.getElementById(`price-${id}`).innerHTML;
                var img = document.getElementById(`image-${id}`).getAttribute('src');
                let item = [product,price,img]
                cart.push(item);
                localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
                
                var content = document.getElementById('products')
                content.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('cart')
            }
```

```html
<div class="product-box">
            <p class="productbadge">10% Off</p>
            <img id="image-1" src="flower1.jpg" height="250px" width="220px">
            <br>
            <div class="productsumm" id="product-1">Red Roses</div>
            <p class="productprice" id="price-1">Rs. 300</p>
            <a class="productbuy" onclick="addItem('1');" align="right" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#basicModal">Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to display an array as the content.

You would need to loop through the content array with a `forEach` loop and display each item separately. You do not need the cart array in this instance. Also when you `JSON.stringify` data you need to `JSON.parse` when retrieving it.

```js
function addItem(id) {
    var product = document.getElementById(`product-${id}`).innerHTML;
    var price = document.getElementById(`price-${id}`).innerHTML;
    var img = document.getElementById(`image-${id}`).getAttribute('src');
    let item = []
    item.push(product, price, img);
    localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(item));
    
    var content = document.getElementById('products')
    var itemArray = JSON.parse(localStroage.getItem('item')

   //Then Loop through the itemArray to display content
```